# Is this a memory leak or a high-memory use JS app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to figure out some performance issues that our node.js app is having. We're on 8.11.1. I haven't dived into heap dumps yet, that's the next step but before I do, I thought I'd seek out another opinion or two. I spun up productions servers at the moments where that line is vertical and since then, it seems like multiple instances are constantly running at about ~60% memory utilization.

If this is not in fact a memory leak, what are some things that we can do to get overall memory utilization down to a lower level?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [node-clinic-docktor](https://github.com/nearform/node-clinic-doctor) ? It helps to figure out your performance issues

Comment: I haven't. Will look into now.